# How can I do a Storm spout that listen an ActiveMQ topic?

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-storm, jms-topic

I programmed a Storm topology that listens on particular topic on kafka with its spouts. Now I have to migrate it on activeMQ. Is possible to reproduce these topics with activeMQ and create spouts that listen them as I did with kafka?

I googled it, but it is not clear how I can send a message to a topic or listen a particular topic. In kafka a do something like

```
data = new KeyedMessage<>("topic", sms);
producer.send(data);
```

to send sms on topic and just create a

```
new kafkaspout("topic")
```

to listen it.
In activeMQ?

It seems I have to do

```
Queue queue = session.createQueue("topic");
```

as many times as the number of topics and then to listen them I have to write something like

```
Queue queue = session.createQueue("topic");
consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
```

I'm not sure this is the right approach and I'd like to be supported by any suggestions!

Comment: Did you ever google it? For real? https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-jms/wiki/Example-Topology

Comment: you should run the example which comes with storm-jms, it will be for sure a good start as it is a working topology based on jms (use a running activemq server for it to work): https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-jms/tree/master/examples